# How do I change the source of an image drag to the desktop using HTML5 Drag and Drop API?

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, draggable, data-transfer

I have a

```
<div draggable><img src="https://example.com/test.webp" alt="testing" /></div>
```

element on a page. By default on MacOS (Chrome or Safari), if you drag the image from the browser to your desktop then `https://example.com/test.webp` gets saved. What I'd like to do is change what gets saved to a different file let's say `https://example.com/test.png` WITHOUT having to do some `src` switching on `dragstart` then reverting back on `dragend` type logic.

I looked at everything in the MDN [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API/Recommended_drag_types#dragging_images) for dragging an image and I couldn't get anything to work. I'd rather not deal with `base64` either. The one approach that got sort of close is to set the datatransfer type on `dragstart`:

```
event.dataTransfer.setData('DownloadURL', 'image/png:test.png:https://example.com/test.png');
```

I think that above statement is for Chrome only? Also, I get a Chrome error saying my organisation has blocked the file transfer due to unmet security policy constraints. Is that maybe because my locally running dev site is on `http://localhost` and the file path is `https` as well as not being same origin?

All my image urls are `.webp` for speed/performance so I'd rather not change them to their `.png` versions. Only when a user drags to the desktop do I want the `png` saved.

The only example I've seen that accomplishes this task is from `Electron.js` here: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/native-file-drag-drop/ but I have no idea how they got it to work.

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)